# How to put data and append to URL with AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax, append, licensing

I want to put the data license variable to URL in AJAX function. For example like this:

`url: "localhost/test/index/license"`

I can't seem to get it working, and the data that pass into my success: `function(data)`, is not the string I wanted. Below is the code. Please help me somebody thank you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            var license = document.forms["license"]["license"].value;
            var check = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$";

            if(license.match(check)) {
                alert("Successful");        
            }
            else {
                alert("Enter the licence in xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx format");
                document.getElementById("license").focus();
            }   

            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "localhost/test/index/",
                data: license,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#message').html(data.trim());
            }})
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax function, add your licence variable like following. and also put your ajax function inside your success if condition

```
var license = document.forms["license"]["license"].value;
 $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "localhost/test/index/"+license,
            data: license,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data.trim());
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a semicolon to the end of ajax bracket and you can add license variable to url as follows :

```
var license = document.forms["license"]["license"].value;

$.ajax({

      url : "localhost/test/index/"+license
});
```